# stupid questionmarks in wordpress using @fontface

Tags: google-chrome, font-face

I made a wordpress theme.

In Chrome on Windows, some stupid question marks are displayed.

The result works fine in all other browsers, including Chrome under macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Declare page encoding:

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html